# Algorithm to score images depending on their square size

Tags: algorithm, rate, scoring

I am trying to create an algorithm that, given a set of  elements that are in a site, would return the one that is more likely to be the "one" describing a product.

This is not a 100% accurate algorithm of course, and will need of people-based selection afterwards, but I am trying to get at least a list of the 3 most probable images.  Here is what I do so far:

1 - Get rid of  which square size is smaller than 50x50px 
2 - Calculate average square size of all  in the page 
3 - Give a score to each , depending on the difference with the average square size (the bigger square size, the more score) 
4 - If width of  is > than (height  * 5), score = score * 0.5 (I do this because this is likely to be a banner in the page).

Here is what I would like to change, but I fail to see what would be a good way to do so. In step 3, what I am doing right now is giving the following score:

```
score_of_image = average_square_size - square_size_image
```

I would like to have a particular amount of points that would be shared out to all the  depending on their size. The share out should reflect the size of one picture related to the others. What would be a good algorithm in order to share out these points?

Comment: Confused! ... are you talking about a simple area calculation or are you talking about how square the images are? I'm presuming you're trying to write some sort of spider type algorithm to collect information from sites regarding products. I would have thought a simple area calculation should give the best indication of a 'product' image. I'm not sure why you are trying to translate this to a score?

Comment: What is an "element"?  Is it a bitmap image?  What is "square size"?  Is that the dimensions of the bitmap image (width times height)?  Your point (4) has some broken grammar, but it seems wrong to me...  a nice square image will have width > height * 0.5, so I would not penalise that.  I might instead penalise an image if width > height * 2, which is very different.

Comment: I think in step 3 you want a percentage difference. So use something like `image_score = square_size_image / average_square_size`. So an image that's larger than the average will have a score that's greater than 1.0.

Comment: @DarrenCrabb I am translating this into score, because I want to take into account other aspects in order to decide what is the product image, not just how "square" an image is.  One of the scores I want to take into account is how "big" in square size (height*width) an image is.

Comment: @j_random_hacker an element would be an <img> element. Square size would be height*width (in pixels). I am penalizing images that have a much bigger width, because those are most likely to be banners in the sites I am trying to parse.

Comment: @HommerSmith: Please reread your expression (4): it penalises the wrong images, I believe.

Comment: @j_random_hacker sorry. I meant 5, not 0.5. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to decide how important some aspects are with regards to others, but you could simply calculate the size of the image (width x height) and use that as the first part of the score. How I'd score this would be to record the area of largest image on the page and work out the others as a percentage of this. I don't think the average image size really adds anything here as I would imagine the largest image is most likely the product image.

Then calculate a separate score for the squareness, doing something like this:-

```
if (height > width) {
    result = (width/height) * max_points_for_squareness;
} else {
    result = (height/width) * max_points_for_squareness;
}
```

So between those two aspects you get two percentages that can be used to distribute a total score however you wish (you could assign more points to squareness if you so wish, or more to image size.

Comment: Good approach and guidance. I have a question though. Why would you compare all the images (in percentage) with the biggest image?

Comment: In order to get a percentage score. So you need to work out which is the biggest image, then divide each smaller image size by the bigger image size and then *100 gives the percentage. That way you always have a consistent range (0-100) to work with, and it enables you to assign an exact amount of points across the whole page, keeping the scoring for the image size in relation to the score for the squareness. You don't have to use 100 though, if you want a bias towards image size you could use a higher number for the multiplier.